# Can I use 2 index actions in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
      @movies = Movie.all  
    end

    def current_user_movie_index
      @movies = current_user.movies 
    end
end
```

I want to show all the movies for all user on index, but I want to add a new link to show only the movies for current_user. Will I do a new action? can I use the same index view for both?

Comment: Yes. You can pass user_id as well to index. You don't need new action

Comment: <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
<p><li><%= link_to movie.title, movie_path(movie) %> </p></li>
<% end %>       this is my code on the index view... what I find a little confusing is to add a link for the users movie only.

Comment: You will have to add more context, like screenshot and what kind of link you want to attach.

Comment: I think using the current_user is the better way, rather than you creating a new action, route .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
      @movies = Movie.all  
    end

    def current_user_movies
      @movies = current_user.movies 
    end
end
```

routes:

```
  resources :movies do
    get :current_user_movies, on: :collection
  end
```

It will now be available at `/movies/current_user_movies`.

Comment: I try to thank you yesterday and this didn't respond. Thanks a lot.

Comment: = my pleasure :)